# How can I get a count of highest orders in my table?

Tags: mysql, sql

pretty new to sql and I'm looking for some insight. We have customers that associate a "customer_type" to them. I was looking to grab all the customers with that specific type and output the top 10 highest customers that have ordered from us with that type. I was able to do that but I'm confused on where to go from here to get that count.

```
SELECT T1.customer_id, T1.customer_name, T1.customer_type, T2.order_id
FROM customers T1
INNER JOIN sales_orders T2 ON T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id
WHERE T1.customer_type = 'R'
ORDER BY
T1.customer_id,
T1.customer_name,
T2.order_id
```

So basically this is outputting something like this:

```
customer A = customer name A = type = order_id A
customer A = customer name A = type = order_id A
customer A = customer name A = type = order_id A
customer B = customer name B = type = order_id B
customer B = customer name B = type = order_id B
customer C = customer name C = type = order_id C
```

etc. etc. What can I do to consolidate that and just find out the top 10 with most order_ids?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Gordon would you be able to help me further? I tried GROUP BY but it's still doing the same thing. Am I missing a count or sum somewhere in here?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.customer_id, T1.customer_name, T1.customer_type, T2.order_id
FROM customer T1
INNER JOIN sale_orders T2 ON T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id
WHERE T1.customer_type = 'R'
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id
```

shows only one entry per customer for me oO and if you want the amount of sales :

```
SELECT T1.customer_id, T1.customer_name, T1.customer_type, T2.order_id ,COUNT(*)
FROM customer T1
INNER JOIN sale_orders T2 ON T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id
WHERE T1.customer_type = 'R'
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id
```

Comment: yeah it just orders it by that. Doesn't solve the problem of multiple companies with multiple order ID's all stating them individually

Comment: oh youre looking for groupby => sometihng like GROUP BY T2.order_id

Comment: I tried that also. Although it does force me to add everything in the SELECT part to the GROUP BY part. But the result still prints out the same duplicate customer names with multiple order_ids. I don't know how to consolidate that. Like if customer_name has 10 order_id's, how do i make it show just that instead of having to manually count it?

Comment: SELECT T1.customer_id, T1.customer_name, T1.customer_type, T2.order_id
FROM customer T1
INNER JOIN sale_orders T2 ON T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id
WHERE T1.customer_type = 'R'
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id

shows only one entry per customer for me oO


and if you want the amount of sales :

SELECT T1.customer_id, T1.customer_name, T1.customer_type, T2.order_id ,COUNT(*)
FROM customer T1
INNER JOIN sale_orders T2 ON T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id

Comment: Odd.. I’ll try again tomorrow since I left for the day. But thank you for the help!